# UITableView theory help for a grizzled old web developer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am a web developer who is trying to transition to Objective-C and Cocoa-touch. I am used to creating a table as a Dom element and then inserting it. If I wanted a link I did that as I went along. Obviously iPhone development is very different. I am looking for either a good explanation of hOw to wrap one's mind around the cocoa way of doing things.

Specifically I am looking to pull data from a web service and then make a drill down 3 or 4 levels deep. If there is a tutorial that shows how to do that perhaps I can learn through that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's [SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) sample code. There's a lot in there, but it's basically what you asked for: an example of grabbing data from a web service and displaying it in a table.

There's a pretty big difference between creating a table on a web page and creating one in an iOS application. In the first case, you're actually writing down the data that gets rendered into a table by a browser. In the second case, you're creating a table object, and that table is like a living, breathing (compared to a web page, anyway) thing that can change through it's lifetime. The table will ask your code for data to display, and also what to do at certain points, such as when a user taps a cell.

Looking at a sample like SeismicXML is a good idea, but you'll still be mystified if you don't take the time to really understand what's going on. (I'm not saying you wouldn't, but there are plenty who don't and are confused to this day.) Go look, and then come back here if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you that was a very helpful example when used in conjunction with Vagrant's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The paradigm for iPhone tables is very different from HTML.  On the web, you build the table and its elements and insert them into the DOM.  On the iPhone, you have a proxy object that answers questions as the table builds itself.  The table will ask the delegate how many entries it has and what it should put in each entry.  That way, the delegate only needs to look up the information that is currently needed by the table, and not the whole thing, which may be only partially displayed.  For instance, the delegate might to database queries as needed.

The simplest way is for your delegate to grab the info it needs from the web site and store it in an array for when the TableView asks for it.

The TableView itself is placed on the screen by calling addSubview: on a parent view.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking more than one question here. You should split them up into multiple, more specific questions.

There are a variety of ways to make HTTP requests, anywhere from using the bundled classes like `NSURL` to using external libraries like ASIHTTPRequest. It also depends on what kind of data you are getting from the Web service -- there are various libraries to parse XML and JSON.

To make a "drill down" I assume you are describing table-based navigation. There are dozens of examples in the Apple sample code archive of projects showing off how to use `UITableViewController`, and probably hundreds available on Stack Overflow.